# why my php array don't appears the changes on it

Tags: php, laravel

hi everyone i'm working on laravel project and for some reason i need to add some attributes to the request using middleware , but my request is nested arrays .
here is the code :

```
// Middleware //
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->json()->add(['created_by_user_id' => Auth::id()]);
    $request->json()->add(['user_id' => Auth::id()]);
    $request->json()->add(['updated_by_user_id' => Auth::id()]);
    $request->json()->add(['deleted_by_user_id' => Auth::id()]);
    foreach ($request->json()->all() as &$json_request){
        if(is_array($json_request)){
            foreach ($json_request as &$item){
                $item += ['created_by_user_id' => Auth::id()];
                $item += ['updated_by_user_id' => Auth::id()];
                $item += ['deleted_by_user_id' => Auth::id()];
            }
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

it can add the attributes to the top level of arrays ,and when it get deeper it works fine but the attributes are not added to the main request , so when i return request's attributes from the controller to see attributes are arrived i get :

```
{
"max_price_new": 9999,
"min_price_new": 1111,
"max_price_old": 9999,
"min_price_old": 1111,
"names": [
    {
        "translation_lang_id": 1,
        "category_name": "test9"
    },
    {
        "translation_lang_id": 2,
        "category_name": "9تجربة"
    }
],
"category_pages": [
    {
        "page_id": 1
    }
],
"category_regions": [
    {
        "region_id": 1
    }
],
"category_photos": [
    {
        "device_id": 1,
        "photo_path": "ite",
        "photo_size": 1
    }
],
"created_by_user_id": 1,
"user_id": 1,
"updated_by_user_id": 1,
"deleted_by_user_id": 1
```

}

Comment: A Request object is usually immutable, so you would need to create a new request object to reflect the changes.

Comment: But I was able to add attributes to the top level of arrays

Comment: if you are using any modern version of Laravel your application is already iterating through the input source and checking every input and transforming them, twice actually, with the `TrimStrings` and `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware, so you could extend the `TransformsRequest` middleware (which the other 2 extend from) to do what you wanted by only overriding the `cleanArray` method and maybe the `clean` method to restrict what is being transformed ... if you feel you really need to go this direction